# Sentry for Spring Version 4

Tags: spring, sentry

Is it possible to use [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/) with [spring](https://spring.io/) **version 4**?

In the documentation, I only found some information about spring 5 and 6.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.sentry.io%2F%3Foriginal_referrer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Version 1.7.x likely will. If not. Before trying that, I'd try each major version and see if it works. Dropping support would land in a major